# using ajax to fill html li

Tags: html, ajax

I currently have a list of items which should be partly filled by an AJAX call. What I have:

```
<li>Hello, username</li>
```

The AJAX call pulls the username from a database. So how do you append that pulled information to display it next to "Hello" since anything in the `li` tags is straight text?

The AJAX:

```
ajax({
    type: "GET"
    url: '../info
    success: function (data){
        if (data != ''){
            var user = info.username;
       }
    } 
})
```

How would the variable user be put in to the list item tag? can you do something like

```
<li>Hello, "$user"</li>
```

Comment: More often your HTML would look similar to `Hello, <li id="userName"></li>`.  
This way you can address the tag and fill the value returned by AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could have your items formatted like `<li>Hello, <span id = "username">username</span>`, it will make your life easier.

Then you could do something like this:

```
if (data != ''){
  var user = info.username;
  $('#username').html(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your AJAX request really return a JavaScript object? I suspect it actually returns JSON, so you're going to need to decode it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../info',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data != '')
        {
            var info = $.parseJSON(data),
                user = info.username;
            $('li').text('Hello, '+user);
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it's probably easier to put a container has the username placeholder,

```
<li>Hello, <span id="username">username</span></li>
```

Then, if you're expecting that the ajax request will return a json formatted response, you have to set the `dataType` option to get it parsed.

```
ajax({
    type: "GET"
    url: '../info',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data) {
            $("#username").text(data.username);
        }
    } 
});
```

If the username it's returned directly as text:

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data != '') {
        $("#username").text(data);
    }
}
```